# Make OpenVPN Client use eth0:1 IP address of OpenVPN Server

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn

I have a VPS (Debian 10) from Hetzner that has eth0 -> IP 22.22.22.22

Then I added a floating IP and now there is also eth0:1 -> IP 44.44.44.44

On OpenVPN server.conf I added `local 44.44.44.44` so it listens on the floating IP.

Then I restarted OpenVPN with `/etc/init.d/openvpn restart`

This is what I have on iptables -S:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0:1 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0:1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0:1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

On client .ovpn config file I added this:

```
remote 44.44.44.44 1194
```

All works fine, the only issue is that on OpenVPN client (Windows 10) when I connect to the OpenVPN server it uses the IP address of eth0 22.22.22.22 and not 44.44.44.44 of eth0:1

Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

The output of `ip route show` is this:

```
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

The output of `if config` is this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 22.22.22.22  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 22.22.22.22
        ether 44:00:00:4b:4e:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eth0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 44.44.44.44  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 44:00:00:4b:4e:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
```

The output of `/etc/network/interfaces.d/60-my-floating-ip.cfg` is this:

```
auto eth0:1
 iface eth0:1 inet static
     address 44.44.44.44
     netmask 32
```

I'd like to make the OpenVPN client use the IP 44.44.44.44 (eth0:1) from OpenVPN server.

Comment: What's in the routing table, `ip route show`

Comment: You want to establish the openvpn connection using the new ip (what you called '44.44.44.44') right ? But why do you have an iptables rule to drop all openvpn traffic incoming on that ip ?

Comment: @tater I added the output of ip route show in the post

Comment: @martin it was a mistake, it is -j ACCEPT (corrected it in the post)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it by doing following steps:

First flush any NAT iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -F
```

And add a new NAT rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 44.44.44.44
```

Then just edit `/etc/iptables/add-openvpn-rules.sh` as this:

```
#iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-soure 44.44.44.44
```